# How do i store an (int)string into an int array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, ascii

```
int ascii[1000] = {0};
string *data = (string*)malloc ( 1000*sizeof( string));
char *text = (char*)malloc ( 1000 *sizeof( char));
cout << "Enter the first arrangement of data." << endl;
cin.getline(text, 1000);
char *token = strtok(text, " ");

while ( token != NULL )
{
    if ( strlen(token) > 0)
    {
        cout << "The tokens are: " << token << endl;
        data[Tcount++] = *token;

    }
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");

    for(i=0; i < (Tcount); i++)
      {
          ascii[i] = (int)data[i]; // error here
      }
```

Im using this code to build a parser and i want to store the ascii values of the tokens which are stored in 'data' into an array named 'ascii'.
  When i run the program i get the error message, "error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'string' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >')
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [`string::data()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/) perhaps? it will give you the array in `char *`. Just tested here and a for with explicit conversion from `char` to `int` worked fine. Edit: Wait.. I think I understand your question wrong.. this only works if you want the ascii int of  each char in the string. Edit 2. If you dont mind hack and if your numbers are limited to 1 digit, you can still use it since you know the ascii value for the number 0.

Comment: `string *data = (string*)malloc ( 1000*sizeof( string));` What the hell is this? 0.o

Comment: yea im pretty new to programming, was trying to create a pointer to a string aloocating memory of 1000 for it to store the 'tokens' in but for some reason only the first character of the token is being stored here.

Comment: Can you clarify this for me? You want the user to input a string with numbers, e.g. `"5905957778553026180268374"`, and store those numbers (the individual digits) in an array (`{5, 9, 0, 5, 9, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 5, 5, 3, 0, 2, 6, 1, 8, 0, 2, 6, 8, 3, 7, 4}`)?

Comment: @ricky3350 yes thats pretty much it, although i want the items which are stored to be separated by a space e.g. if asd = s + 3  
i want the stored items in the array to be:
{asd, =, s, +, 3}

Comment: Am I right in saying that the vast majority of this post is irrelevant and you're actually asking how to parse a numeric `string` into an `int` in C++? Because there is loads of information on how to do that, both here and elsewhere on the web. At least here you also get, for free, warned away from this terrible, terrible C mashup you've got going on!

Comment: Wait, how do you expect `asd` to become stored in an `int`??

Comment: Don't use `malloc` / `free` to allocate C++ objects such as `std::string`, use the `new` / `delete` operator instead. That because a constructor / destructor might need to be called for those objects. Plus you don't even need it here, just use `std::string data;` and it'll manage memory allocation for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing before the main event here. Obviously you're allowed to use std::string so, let's get the data in a more civilized fashion.

```
std::vector<std::string> data;
std::string line;
std::getline(cin, line); //read a whole line
std::stringstream tokenizer(line); // stuff the line into an object that's 
                                   // really good at tokenizing
std::string token;
while (tokenizer >> token) // one by one push a word out of the tokenizer 
{
    data.push_back(token); //and stuff it into a vector
}
```

we now have all of the individual words on the line packed into a nice resizable container, a vector. No messy dynamic memory to clean up.

Step 2: turn those strings into ints. 'Fraid you can't do that, ace. You could take a string that represents a number and turn it into an int. That's easy. Dozens of ways to do it. I like strtol.

But the ascii values are character by character. A string is a variable number of characters. You can pack one into an int, shift the int over by the width of one character and stuff in another, but you're going to run out of space after probably 4 or 8 characters.

Let's go with that, shall we? And we'll do it the old way without an iterator.

```
std::string data;
int ascii = 0;

if (data.length() > 0)
{
    ascii |= data[index];
    for(size_t index = 0; index < data.length(); index++)
    {
        ascii <<= 8; //we're talking ascii here so no unicode bit counting games 
        ascii |= data[index];
    }
}
```

Done. Not very useful unless all the strings are pretty short, but done.

Instead if you're going to do a parser why not go full geek and try this:

```
typedef void handlerfunc();
std::map<std::string, handlerfunc> parser;

parser["do something"] = somethingfunc;
parser["do something else"] = somethingelsefunc;
```

Where somethingfunc is a function that looks like `void somethingfunc()` that, obviously, does something. Dito somethingelsefunc. Only it does somethingelse.

Usage could be as simple as:

```
parser[token]();
```

But it's not. Sigh.

It's more like

```
found = parser.find(token)
if (found != parser.end())
{
    found->second();
    return CMD_OK;
}
else
{
    return CMD_NOT_FOUND;
}
```

But seriously, look into some of the fun stuff a good container can do for you. Save a ton of time.

I crapped out all of the code without a compiler. Please let me know if I borked any of it.